# which join goes faster: 1 key+ hard coded vs 2 key

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

i just want to know which Join will go faster.

Generally, table A's 2 key columns join  to table B's 2 key columns, all are indexed.

Two table base on million row level.

Should be like this:

```
select * 
from  A 
left join B 
on  A.key1=B.key1
and A.key2=B.key2
..............
..............
```

But if i want Particular key value at  `key2`,  `key2='AA'`which will be faster:

Plan A:

```
select * 
from  A 
left join B 
on  A.key1=B.key1
and A.key2=B.key2
where A.key2='AA'
```

Plan B:

```
select * 
from  A 
left join B 
on  A.key1=B.key1
where A.key2='AA' and B.key2='AA'
```

thanks

Comment: Why don't you just check the execution plan out....? That being said, I think they both will be the same.

Comment: Choose *View execution plan*

Answer (score 1):

The two queries are **NOT SEMANTICALLY EQUIVALENT**.

When you put a column from a `LEFT JOIN`ed table into the `WHERE` clause, you make it an `INNER JOIN`. If there was no matching record in `B` you won't get the record from `A`.

Your options are to use it in the `WHERE` clause like you are in the first option, or to put it into the `JOIN`:

```
left join B 
on  A.key1=B.key1
AND a.Key1 = 'AA'
```

...which is again the same execution plan in most RDBMS.

As a rule for readability, you want this in the `WHERE` clause since that's where the next person will look for the filter.

Answer (score 0):

The only definitive way to tel lwould be to try it both ways and measure them.  IT will depend on what indexes are available and how the optimizer decides to use them.

If there was a composite index on `(key1, key2)` on each table I'd expect the join + filter to be faster if there were any difference.  If there was only an index on `key1` I would expect preformance to be about the same.